# How to configure .htaccess for custom urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to know how to set up .htaccess to make custom URL as follows:

"www.examplesite.com/main/sub/sub_sub"

i have the follow code in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !http://localhost/routeB/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) routeB/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ routeB/index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Help me please!

i'm making a framework

Comment: Or redirect all URI's to a router file and handle them there..?

Comment: No, i only to do the URL customizeds. Or also! :D